# How to simulate the screen in background?

Tags: operating-system

My A.I. project needs to make searches on internet and scan the results by making screenshots of a virtual screen in background. It will run on a server, so it can't put the data on the real screen. It will work while each user of this service is doing other things and see them on his monitor. The AI will receive the data from the port 80 in http or htts and I have to create a virtual screen for each search to do, from which to catpure images while the words are directly from the http flow. Is there anyone who knows how to create that virtual screen?

Comment: Which Operating System?

Comment: It is not fundamental, if possible Windows Server, otherwise it's ok even with Linux.